# jQuery Dynamic Form Submission Errors

Tags: jquery, forms

In my current project I need to "round up" a variable selection of input, select and other form fields and submit them as a form.  In order to accomplish this I am creating a `<form>` element on-the-fly.  Something along the lines of

**HTML**

```
<a id="fire" href="#" title="submit form">Submit form</a>
<input id='inpQ' name='q' type='text' required/>
```

**JS**

```js
$('#fire').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var opts = {
        'action': 'http://www.google.com/search',
        'target': '_blank'
    }
    var newForm = $('<form>', opts).append($('#inpQ').clone());
    newForm.submit();
});
```

I should explain that I need to retain the original elements rather than just sequestering them for use in the form - hence the .clone().

For a working demo see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YqGLH/195/)

This works - but only up to a point.  The issues I have run into

- Webkit browsers: Works but the injunction to **require** the 'inpQ value is ignored by the browser.
- In Firefox and IE10 it does not work at all.  In the latter I get console errors along the lines of Access is Denied and $ is undefined.  In Firefox there are no errors but... nothing happens.

Perhaps someone here could shed some light on some of these issues?

Comment: Chrome 29 OS X 10.8.4, works exactly as you desired, nothing wrong happended

Comment: Op says working on chrome not working in IE 10

Comment: Chrome on Windows works just fine too but ***require*** is ignored.  Are you telling me that it is not ignored in OS X?

Comment: I have not managed to get this working in Firefox - it turned out that in FF the form had to be appended to the document body in order to be submitted.  See [http://jsfiddle.net/YqGLH/198/](http://jsfiddle.net/YqGLH/198/).  However, the problem with require persists and sweet ol IE still throws script errors.

Comment: Why not just submit the original form, same thing you are trying to do.

Comment: Blank fields won't be a matter, it won't be submitted.

Comment: Like I mention in my post - in this particular application it is not possible to forsee what has to be submitted by neatly putting it inside a form.  The original HTML has no (and cannot have) any forms.  I need to "round up" form inputs for submission dynamically.

Comment: I am sorry - it looks like you have not understood what I have said.  In the normal course of events an HTML5 compliant browser will throw up a warning when a required field is left blank.  This is not happening with the dynamic submit.

Comment: And what errors you get from `FF` console ?

Comment: As I mention in my comment above - the issue with FF was the need to append the dynamic form element to the docuemnt body.  However, this does not fix the ***require*** problem.

Comment: Check the updated answer (works in `IE-10` too) and also remember, when someone try to help you, you should appreciate it even the answer may doesn't help but it looks very odd when `OP` himself down votes on an answer, it's technically right (you can down vote) but not the right way to show your gratitude, you can just tell the contributor that the answer doesn't solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try something like this

```
$('#fire').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var url = 'http://www.google.com/search';
    var opts = { 'action':url, 'target':'_blank', 'style':'display:none' };
    var inpQ =  $('#inpQ').clone();
    var newForm =$('<form/>', opts).append(inpQ);

    $('body').append(newForm);
    newForm.trigger('submit').remove();
});
```

[**Working Example.**](http://jsfiddle.net/YqGLH/200/) (Tested in Chrome and FF).

**Update :**
You can't do it using `required` attribute in this way, you have to keep the form's `input` field `focusable/visible` to make it working with `html5 required attribute`, you can use `js` to validate the form using a `class=required` in inputs on submission, like (also works in `IE-10`) :

```
$(function(){

    $('#fire').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var url = 'http://www.google.com/search';
        var opts = {
            'id':'vForm',
            'action':url,
            'target':'_blank',
            'style':'display:none'
        };
        var inpQ =  $('#inpQ').clone();
        var newForm =$('<form/>', opts).append(inpQ);

        $('body').append(newForm);
        newForm.trigger('submit');
        newForm.remove();
    });

    $(document).on('submit', '#vForm', function(e){
        $('#vForm .rerquired').each(function(){
            if(!this.value.length) {
                e.preventDefault();
                alert(this.name +' is a required field');
                $('#vForm').remove();
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
});
```

In `Internet explorer-10` it was not working because of `jQuery` version but now it works.

[**Working Example.**](http://jsfiddle.net/YqGLH/204/) (Tested in `IE-10`, `FF` and `Chrome`).

Comment: Would you care to tell me the reason for down voting, So everyone (including me) can be sure what is the problem with this code.

Comment: @DroidOS, you should explain for down voting this answer, because this is working.

Comment: DroidOS, To be honest, I still now didn't get the reason that, why OP himself down voted at an answer even the answer is working, IMO. I really want an explanation to clarify myself, maybe i missed something and didn't really get it but you should at least tell me where i'm wrong instead of just down voting.

Comment: My question is regarding why ***required*** is ignored and why it does not work in IE10.  With Chrome & Safari it is only ***required*** that is the issue.  With Firefox you need to append the new form to the body before submitting it - which I have mentioned in one of my comments.  I may have been severe with the downvote so I'll try to cancel it.  However, you are only paraphrasing what I already know and have stated.

Comment: That (`required`) is not possible this way, you have to keep the form `input` focusable, otherwise it won't work, instead you have to rely on `js` to check on submission using a `class`.

Comment: Thanks.  I have accepted your answer.  The issue with required not being enforceable on hidden/invisible form inputs is perfectly reasonable when one thinks about it.  The fact that IE is falling down with the latest versions of jQuery is something of a pain but not entirely unexpected I guess.

Comment: @DroidOS, Welcome and you should also undo the down vote, you probably forgot it, IMO.

Comment: @DroidOS, Ah! Glad to see that :-)